# VNC on Vista

Tags: windows, windows-vista, kvm-virtualization, vnc, video

I'm using UltraVNC on my Vista machine, and it's giving me very poor performance, even over a 300 mbs network.  It seems to be doing screen polling.

I looked, and it doesn't look like the video hook driver is working.  Does anyone know if you can use a video hook driver with Vista?

Comment: Which version of UltraVNC are you using?  I recommend 1.0.5.6

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why bother with VNC when you've got RDP out of the box on Vista?  There are basic RDP clients for just about every platform these days.

Comment: This is Vista Home Premium, which does not include RDP.

Comment: Also note that if you _do_ want to run RDP on Vista Home, there is a way: http://serverfault.com/questions/6944/remote-desktop-to-vista-home-premium-pcs

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes you can install the [video hook driver](http://sc.uvnc.com/drivers.zip) on Vista, but you have to do it manually.

To improve speed, right click on the UltraVNC icon on the taskbar and select properties.  Then tick the following boxes:

- Poll Full Screen
- Poll Foreground Window
- Poll Window Under Cursor
- System HookDll

[image]

If you are using the video hook driver, check if the **Video Hook Driver** option is ticked.

Then press **OK** to save the new settings.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the UltraVNC Video Driver?  The latest is 1.0.5:

http://sc.uvnc.com/105/drivers.zip

-Adam