# Remote Desktop to Vista Home Premium PCs

Tags: windows-vista, remote-desktop

Is there a way of connecting via Remote Desktop to a Vista Home Premium system, or do I need to use VNC instead?

Edit: I'm having a bad day with TLA's. Sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From **"[Remote Desktop Connection: frequently asked questions](http://windowshelp.microsoft.com/Windows/en-US/help/f55326fa-e629-423b-abba-b30f76cc61e61033.mspx)"**:

You **cannot** use Remote Desktop Connection to connect to remote (host) computers running the following editions of Windows Vista:

- Windows Vista Starter
- Windows Vista Home Basic
- Windows Vista Home Basic N
- Windows Vista Home Premium

However, any edition of Windows Vista can be running on your computer (the one you want to connect from).

So, you'll have to run an alternative software like [TightVNC](http://www.tightvnc.com/).

Comment: That also says "You cannot use Remote Desktop Connection to connect to remote computers running Windows XP." - which is plain wrong!

Comment: Roddy, I guess that text on that Microsoft page means "XP" vs. "XP Professional Edition." Very confusing though...

Answer (score 2):

For Windows Vista Home Premium that basicly doesn't support RPD, you can use Microsoft Live Mesh that'll allow you to remote desktop your computer.

Link : https://www.mesh.com/welcome/default.aspx

Hope this help.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but it's a hack and probably illegal. Which is why I won't explain the process here, and link to it instead (I hope that is okay here).

http://digg.com/microsoft/Remote_Desktop_Hack_for_Vista_Home_Premium

Answer (score 0):

Remote Desktop and VPN are not related technologies. You can use one without the other.

Comment: My bad. VNC was what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go with a good remote desktop program that's free, try

[Teamviewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/index.aspx)

I've used it for years. It's free for home use, very fast, and it's interface is very similar to a RDP connection (tab at the top of the window that auto-hides). Very easy to install and connect to also.

I might be wrong but I think it's performance may be faster than VNC

Answer (score 0):

I've been using Live Mesh for this - seems to work well for getting to the PCs at my house.  You can check it out [here](http://www.mesh.com).